# Restrict vLine WebRtc API to not use servers

Tags: web, webrtc, vline

Is there anyway to restrict the vLine API to only use RTCPeerConnection without servers (only direct browser to browser communication)?

Regards,

Raveash

Answer (score 0):

We currently don't provide this functionality directly, but depending on your use case we may have something that will work. Could you explain your use case?

Comment: I was interested in using the Higher Level API that vLine provides to work with WebRTC but not use the underlying servers (i.e. STUNT) to facilitate the communication.

One reason I want this is to allow a developer to install my application, that uses the vLine API, without requiring them to sign up or pay for for a vLine account in order to start using it.

My assumption would be that if the application only uses a direct WebRTC Peer to Peer connection, the developer installing the application will not need to incur the cost of using vLine's servers unless they decided it was beneficial.

Comment: @RaveAsh It's not quite that simple. Even if the media for the call is not routed through our cloud, all of the signaling (call session management, presence, text chat, etc.) goes through our cloud. Currently, while we're in beta the service is free. If you send an email to support@vline.com we can give you a quote for pricing after the beta period ends.

Answer (score -1):

You can use our open source easyRTC client and server to do that instead of vLine.  The pro for this is that it is free except for your server costs. The con is that you have to run your own server. vLine is one of the good Platform as a Service companies and they will save you effort.